# How to filter other parent of child with Vapor?

Tags: vapor

[image]

I have this request:

```
router.get("/fetchOngoingReleases") { (request) -> Future<[ReleaseOut]> in
        return Release.query(on: request).filter(\.inprogress == true).all().map { releases in
                var result: [ReleaseOut] = []
                for r in releases {
                    var pageEvents: [Event] = []

                    let num = r.releaseUsers.query(on: request).filter(\.user.fbId ~~ "something").count()

                    var needAuthentication: Bool
                    if num == 0 {
                        needAuthentication = true
                    } else {
                        needAuthentication = false
                    }
                    let rOut = ReleaseOut(fbId: r.fbId, name: r.name, purpose: r.purpose, needAuthentication: needAuthentication)
                    result.append(rOut)
                }
                return result
        }
    }
}
```

It says **I can not access (???)** `releaseUser.user.fbId` in the query?

Here the data model:

[image]

and in code

```
final class Release: Content {
    var id: Int?
    var fbId: String
    var inprogress: Bool?
    var name: String
    var purpose: String

    /// Creates a new `Release`.
    init(id: Int? = nil, fbId: String, name: String, purpose: String = "normal selling") {
        self.id = id
        self.fbId = fbId
        self.name = name
        self.purpose = purpose
    }
}

extension Release {
    var releaseUsers: Children<Release, ReleaseUser> {
        return children(\.releaseId)
    }
}

final class ReleaseUser: Content {
    var id: Int?
    var releaseId: Release.ID
    var userId: User.ID

    init(id: Int? = nil, releaseId: Release.ID, userId: User.ID) {
        self.id = id
        self.releaseId = releaseId
        self.userId = userId
    }
}

extension ReleaseUser {
    var user: Parent<ReleaseUser, User> {
        return parent(\.userId)
    }
}

final class User: Content {
    var id: Int?
    var fbId: String
    var name: String

    init(id: Int? = nil, fbId: String, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.fbId = fbId
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so there are several things going on here, but the main concept is that you can't just jump across different tables like that - you need to use a `JOIN` to join the `ReleaseUser` table to the `User` table so you can then query on the `fbId`

Comment: I thought is it like `Core Data` and I can chain queries like this: `relationship1.relationships2.attribute`. But seems not.

Comment: No unfortunately not, you'll need to build that query manually

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your query to:

```
Release.query(on: request).filter(\.inprogress == true).join(\ReleaseUser.releaseId, to:\Release.Id).join(\ReleaseUser.userId, to:\User.Id).alsoDecode(User.self).all()
```

The `alsoDecode` will give you a tuple with the first position containing your original  `Release` instance and the second containing the corresponding `User` instance. So, `fbId` should be available as:

```
r.1.fbId
```

In your case.